# Mysql interpolation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following data in mysql:

```
date,value,id

2016-01-01,0,1
2016-01-04,1,2
2016-01-10,2,3
2016-01-25,1,4
2016-01-26,10,5
```

I have another table with just dates and ids that I want to insert in the first table using the following rule: set the value as the value at the last date before the date of the given id. That is, if I have to introduce the following elements:

```
date,id

2016-01-02,6
2016-01-03,7
2016-01-11,8
2016-01-28,9
2016-01-28,10
```

I want the final table to be:

```
date,value,id

2016-01-01,0,1
2016-01-04,1,2
2016-01-10,2,3
2016-01-25,1,4
2016-01-26,10,5
2016-01-02,0,6
2016-01-03,0,7
2016-01-11,28
2016-01-28,10,9
2016-01-28,10,10
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  Do you want to "insert" the values or create  a result set?

Comment: 5.7.19, and creating a result set would be fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the "previous" value using a correlated subquery:

```
select x.date, x.id,
       (select t.value
        from t
        where t.date <= x.date
        order by t.date desc
        limit 1
       ) as value
from (select '2016-01-02' as date, 6 as id union all
      select '2016-01-03' as date, 7 as id union all
      select '2016-01-11' as date, 8 as id union all
      select '2016-01-28' as date, 9 as id union all
      select '2016-01-28' as date, 10 as id 
     ) x;
```

If you want to insert these into the table, simply put an `insert` clause before the `select`.  If you want a result set with all rows, then use `union all` with the other table.